# ¿Por qué obtengo el problema Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null?

Tags: jsf

Buenos dias me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto en el cual me genera el siguiente error en el indexBean

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;



/**
 *
 * @author Alexander Gil
 */
@Named(value = "indexBean")
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private ServicioUsuarioLocal servicioUsuarioLocal;
    private Usuario usuario;    
    private List<Usuario> listaDeUsuarios;


    /**
     * Creates a new instance of IndexBean
     */
    public IndexBean() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializarBean() {
        usuario = new Usuario();
        listaDeUsuarios = servicioUsuarioLocal.obtenerTodosLosUsuarios();
    }

    public void listenerBotonInicioDeSesion() {
        List<Usuario> usuariosEncontrados = servicioUsuarioLocal.obtenerTodosLosUsuarios();
        for (Usuario u : usuariosEncontrados) {
            System.out.println("usuario: " + u.getNombre());
        }
    }

    public void listenerValidarInicioDeSesion() {

    }

    public List<Usuario> getListaDeUsuarios() {
        return listaDeUsuarios;
    }

    public void setListaDeUsuarios(List<Usuario> listaDeUsuarios) {
        this.listaDeUsuarios = listaDeUsuarios;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }    
}
```

y el index.xhtml

```
    <div class="header">
        <h:form id="signup"
                style="text-align: center; margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%;">
            <p:growl id="growl" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>

            <h:graphicImage value="imagenes/businessman223.png" width="50" height="50"/>
            <br></br><br></br>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:outputLabel for="txtUsuario" value="Usuario"/>

                <p:inputText id="txtUsuario" required="true" value="#{indexBean.usuario.nombre}"
                             requiredMessage="Usuario obligatorio"/>

                <p:outputLabel for="txtClave" value="Clave"/>

                <p:password id="txtClave" required="true" value="#{indexBean.usuario.password}"
                            feedback="true"
                            promptLabel="Digite su contraseña Por Favor" weakLabel="Minimo"
                            goodLabel="Medio" strongLabel="Maximo" requiredMessage="Clave obligatoria"/>
                <h:column/>
                <p:commandButton value="Iniciar Sesion" icon="ui-icon-key"                                 
                                 actionListener="#{indexBean.listenerBotonInicioDeSesion()}"
                                 process="@this, txtUsuario, txtClave" 
                                 action="principal"/>

            </h:panelGrid>


        </h:form>
    </div>

</h:body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es de uso de anotaciones. La anotación `@Named` proveniente de `javax.inject.Named` pertenece al uso de CDI, mientras que la anotación `@SessionScoped` proveniente de `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` pertenece a managed beans de JSF 2.0 en adelante. Estas anotaciones no se pueden mezclar entre sí, por lo que tu bean está mal configurado y genera el error.

Utiliza etiquetas netamente de CDI o de JSF, no una mezcla de ambas.

Solución 1: utiliza solo anotaciones de CDI. Para ello, `@SessionScoped` debería provenir de `javax.enterprise.context`. Asimismo, asegúrate de que tu aplicación trabaja con CDI, de lo contrario esto te traerá más problemas que soluciones.

Solución 2: utilizar solo anotaciones de JSF. Para ello, deberás reemplazar `@Named` con `@ManagedBean` proveniente de `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`. Según veo tu código, esta es la solución que aplicaría para tu caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias esa era la solucion.

Comment: Por favor no te olvides de aceptar la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

Estas creando el usuario en el método **@PostConstruct** pero no inicializas sus atributos:

```
@PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {
    usuario = new Usuario();
    listaDeUsuarios = servicioUsuarioLocal.obtenerTodosLosUsuarios();
}
```

Cuando accedes a la propiedad esta a **null** mediante

```
value="#{indexBean.usuario.nombre}"
```

Prueba algo de este estilo:

```
@PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {
    // tambien puedes hacerlo por un constructor que te crees estilo Usuario("pepe","mypassword");
    usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.setNombre("pepe");
    usuario.setPassword("mypassword");
    listaDeUsuarios = servicioUsuarioLocal.obtenerTodosLosUsuarios();
}
```

Mira a ver si esto te lo soluciona.

Comment: No me funciono pero igualmente muchas gracias